# returning value without breaking a loop

Tags: python, loops, return

I intend to make a `while` loop inside a defined function. In addition, I want to return a value on every iteration. Yet it doesn't allow me to iterate over the loop.
Here is the plan:

```
def func(x):
    n=3
    while(n>0): 
        x = x+1  
        return x

print(func(6))
```

I know the reason to such issue-`return` function breaks the loop.
Yet, I insist to use a defined function. Therefore, is there a way to somehow iterate over returning a value, given that such script is inside a defined function?

Comment: The condition `n > 0` will never be `False` in your example

Comment: what do expect the output to be?

Comment: Look into [`generators`](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to return a value and continue the function in the next call at the point where you returned, use `yield` instead of return.

Technically this produces a so called generator, which gives you the return values value by value. With next() you can iterate over the values. You can also convert it into a list or some other data structure.

Your original function would like this:

```
def foo(n):
  for i in range(n):
    yield i
```

And to use it:

```
gen = foo(100)
print(next(gen))
```

or

```
gen = foo(100)
l = list(gen)
print(l)
```

Keep in mind that the generator calculates the results 'on demand', so it does not allocate too much memory to store results. When converting this into a list, all results are caclculated and stored in the memory, which causes problems for large n.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your use case, you may simply use print(x) inside the loop and then  `return` the final value.

If you actually need to return intermediate values to a caller function, you can use `yield`.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a generator for that, so you could yield values from your generator.

Example:

```
def func(x):
    n=3
    while(n>0): 
        x = x+1  
        yield x
func_call = func(6)  # create generator
print(next(func_call)) # 7
print(next(func_call)) # 8
```